# "Under construction" message when accessing localhost

Tags: iis, iis-6

I have installed iis6 on Windows Server 2003 R2 Service Pack 2. Home directory is `c:\inetpub\wwwroot` , `Enable default content page` is enabled and iisatart.htm is added. Now when I try to access localhost I get the following error:

```
Under Contsruction
The site you are trying to view does not currently have a default page. .....
```

I know it might be a simple problem but I googled a lot and could not find any solution. Any help is apprreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `Enable default Content page` you have to actually choose the defauly page that you want. see [here](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/dc6eb1b4-9028-4308-9935-52b64edfad36.mspx?mfr=true) from Microsoft for instructions, it's pretty simple.

Comment: I have added iisatart.htm to the list. This file exists in Home directory.